# "Median color" of a Image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb, median

I'm doing some basic image processing in matlab (2010a) and I want to display some standard information of different pictures like the histogram etc.

Is there a way to get the "median color" of a whole image without iterate the pixels manually for each RGB color?

All I found is about the median filter, but I look for something like the function `mean` to get the average color.

Image-Processing-Toolbox would be available.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont quit get  this question. What is an average color? for black and white there is an easy scale we call it the grayscale... But for an RGB set? do you mean maybe _Hue_? see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue how to calculate the hue, or maybe you mean _Colorfulness_ ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorfulness

Answer (score 0):

Median is not defined for vectors (RGB triplets in your case).
What you can compute is the median along R, G, and B channels seperately

```
median( reshape(img, [], 3 ), 2 ); % returns a row vector of median R,G and B
```

See Matlab's [doc on `median`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html) for more info.

Comment: Or is the Q to apply median to the "color dimension"? MedianColors = median(img, 3);

Comment: What I posted, the median across 3 points, is not going to give a very sensible output, the more I think about it. For that kind of operation, mean is much more appropriate, I think.